# How to Call Client Machine Hosted WcfService From WebApplication Hosted on Another Server?

Tags: web-services, wcf, wcf-data-services, remote-server, wcf-security

I have a WcfService hosted on Console Application on user(client) computer that provides access to document scanner device (Avision AD240) to scan documents and want to call this service from another website (e.g hosted on [www.someotherdomain.com](http://www.someotherdomain.com)).
In summary: my website users work with jetScan document scanner and want to upload scanned images on the server in the website. I've done that in local IIS but I don't know how to address the local hosted service in the remote server hosted web application.

My WcfService Web.Config file looks like:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<configuration>

  <appSettings>
    <add key="aspnet:UseTaskFriendlySynchronizationContext" value="true" />
  </appSettings>
  <system.web>
    <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.7.2" />
    <httpRuntime targetFramework="4.7.2"/>
  </system.web>
  <system.serviceModel>
    <bindings>
      <basicHttpBinding>
        <binding name="BasicHttpBinding_IScannerService" maxReceivedMessageSize="2147483647">
 
        </binding>
      </basicHttpBinding>
    </bindings>
    <behaviors>
      <serviceBehaviors>
        <behavior>
          <!-- To avoid disclosing metadata information, set the values below to false before deployment -->
          <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" httpsGetEnabled="true"/>
          <!-- To receive exception details in faults for debugging purposes, set the value below to true.  Set to false before deployment to avoid disclosing exception information -->
          <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="false"/>
        </behavior>
      </serviceBehaviors>
    </behaviors>
    <services>
      <service name="WcfServiceScanner.ScannerService">
        <endpoint address="" binding="basicHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="BasicHttpBinding_IScannerService" contract="WcfServiceScanner.IScannerService">
          <identity>
            <dns value="localhost" />
          </identity>
        </endpoint>
        <endpoint address="mex" binding="mexHttpBinding" contract="IMetadataExchange" />
        <host>
          <baseAddresses>
            <add baseAddress="http://localhost:8733/Design_Time_Addresses/WcfServiceScanner/WcfServiceScanner/" />
          </baseAddresses>
        </host>
      </service>
    </services>
    <protocolMapping>
    </protocolMapping>
    <serviceHostingEnvironment aspNetCompatibilityEnabled="true" multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="true" />
  </system.serviceModel>
  <system.webServer>
    <!--<modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true"/>-->
    <!--
        To browse web app root directory during debugging, set the value below to true.
        Set to false before deployment to avoid disclosing web app folder information.
      -->
    <directoryBrowse enabled="true"/>
    <httpProtocol>
      <customHeaders>
        <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Origin" value="*"/>
        <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Headers" value="Content-Type, Accept" />
        <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Methods" value="POST,GET,OPTIONS" />
        <add name="Access-Control-Max-Age" value="1728000" />
      </customHeaders>
    </httpProtocol>
  </system.webServer>

</configuration>
```

and a part of my remote server web application web.config file looks like :

```
  <system.serviceModel>
    <bindings>
      <basicHttpBinding>
        <binding name="BasicHttpBinding_IScannerService"  maxReceivedMessageSize="2147483647"/>
      </basicHttpBinding>
      <netTcpBinding>
        <binding name="NetTcpBinding_IScannerService">
          <security>
            <transport sslProtocols="None" />
          </security>
        </binding>
      </netTcpBinding>
    </bindings>
    <client>
      <endpoint address="http://localhost:8080/WcfService" binding="basicHttpBinding"
        bindingConfiguration="BasicHttpBinding_IScannerService" contract="WcfScannerService.IScannerService"
        name="BasicHttpBinding_IScannerService" />
      <endpoint address="net.tcp://localhost:8090/WcfService" binding="netTcpBinding"
        bindingConfiguration="NetTcpBinding_IScannerService" contract="WcfScannerService.IScannerService"
        name="NetTcpBinding_IScannerService">
        <identity>
          <userPrincipalName value="DESKTOP-KILE609\Hosein" />
        </identity>
      </endpoint>
    </client>
  </system.serviceModel>
```

Answer (score 0):

The code is fine if it is locally accessible.
The following steps may help you:

1. Make sure the network is working on the other machine.
2. Check whether the IP address and port are occupied or shielded by the firewall.
3. Adding ?wsdl in the end of the url,if that works and show you an xml file, the service is reachable.

Thanks.